# How to convert a YV12 image to BGRA using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

To convert YV12 to BGRA, I do like below:

```
 cv::Mat yuv(height * 3/2, width, CV_8UC1, src);
 cv::Mat dst;
 cv::cvtColor(yuv, dst, CV_YUV2BGRA_YV12);
```

That code will work when the "src" is a contiguous buffer.

In case I have a YV12 buffer with its Y, U, V components stored in 3 separate planes and they are not contiguous, how can I do the conversion using cvtColor()?

Comment: copy the components into one Mat, possibly using reshapes and `copyTo`. sorry, that's it. -- or use some driver/hardware facility instead, which may be faster than doing it host-side

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz. If want to copy the image's planes into one cv::Mat I would have not asked SO here.

Comment: you can wait for an "answer" but there won't be any other. OpenCV has this procedure and no other. don't blame me for it.

Comment: I just gave my thought about the purpose of my question. Why do you think I "blamed" you?

Answer (score 2):

For using `cv::cvtColor`, you have to copy the separate components into continuous image buffer as noted by Christoph Rackwitz.

I don't think copying the components is trivial, and I think you deserve an answer.

---

The continuous YV12 image applies the following structure:

- Y (cols x rows) - Top Image.
- V (cols/2 x rows/2) - Below Y
- U (cols/2 x rows/2) - Below V

We may allocate a continuous buffer, and copy the components to the allocated buffer.

Since OpenCV "hides" the buffer in the `data` member, I thought it would be simpler to allocate the buffer using `new`, and create a cv:Mat that "wraps" the buffer.

Example:

```
unsigned char *YV12 = new unsigned char[cols*rows*3/2]; //Allocate continuous memory buffer for storing YV12 in as single buffer.

cv::Mat inYV12 = cv::Mat(rows*3/2, cols, CV_8UC1, YV12); //cv::Mat wrapper of YV12 buffer.
```

Defining cv:Mat wrappers to Y, U and V, sharing the continuous buffer:

```
cv::Mat inY0 = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, YV12); //Copy Y color channel.
cv::Mat inU0 = cv::Mat(rows/2, cols/2, CV_8UC1, YV12 + cols*rows); //U color channel (after Y).
cv::Mat inV0 = cv::Mat(rows/2, cols/2, CV_8UC1, YV12 + cols*rows + cols*rows/4); //V color channel (after U).
```

Copy the three separate images to the continuous image:

```
inY.copyTo(inY0);
inU.copyTo(inU0);
inV.copyTo(inV0);
```

---

Complete code sample:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main()
{
    const int cols = 192;
    const int rows = 108;

    //Read Y, U and V into 3 separate buffers for testing. 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *Y = new unsigned char[cols*rows];
    unsigned char *U = new unsigned char[cols*rows / 4];
    unsigned char *V = new unsigned char[cols*rows / 4];

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("test.yv12", "rb");   //Note: In Visual Studio, you may have to use fopen_s or define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    fread(Y, 1, cols*rows, f); //Read Y
    fread(U, 1, cols*rows/4, f); //Read U
    fread(V, 1, cols*rows/4, f); //Read V
    fclose(f);

    //Define cv::Mat "wrappers".
    cv::Mat inY = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, Y);
    cv::Mat inU = cv::Mat(rows/2, cols/2, CV_8UC1, U);
    cv::Mat inV = cv::Mat(rows/2, cols/2, CV_8UC1, V);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    unsigned char *YV12 = new unsigned char[cols*rows*3/2]; //Allocate continuous memory buffer for storing YV12 in as single buffer.

    cv::Mat inYV12 = cv::Mat(rows*3/2, cols, CV_8UC1, YV12); //cv::Mat wrapper of YV12 buffer.

    //Define cv::Mat "wrappers" to the continuous memory buffer.
    cv::Mat inY0 = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, YV12); //Copy Y color channel.
    cv::Mat inU0 = cv::Mat(rows/2, cols/2, CV_8UC1, YV12 + cols*rows); //U color channel (after Y).
    cv::Mat inV0 = cv::Mat(rows/2, cols/2, CV_8UC1, YV12 + cols*rows + cols*rows/4); //V color channel (after U).

    //Copy the three separate images to the continuous image.
    inY.copyTo(inY0);
    inU.copyTo(inU0);
    inV.copyTo(inV0);

    //Convert YV12 to BGRA:
    cv::Mat dstBGRA;
    //cv::cvtColor(inYV12, dstBGRA, cv::CV_YUV2BGRA_YV12);
    cv::cvtColor(inYV12, dstBGRA, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YV12);

    //Release memory
    delete[] Y;
    delete[] U;
    delete[] V;
    delete[] YV12;

    cv::imwrite("dstBGRA.png", dstBGRA);    //Save output for testing

    //Show result (for testing):
    cv::imshow("dstBGRA", dstBGRA);
    cv::waitKey();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Input (converted to continuous grayscale image):
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rotem for your thorough answer. Your solution may work somehow, however it uses so many deep copy operations that hurts the performace. I will upvote you but won't accept your answer.

Comment: Using deep copy is the price to pay for solving the problem using OpenCV. Do you want me to try solving it using [swscale](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/swscale-example_8c-source.html)?

Comment: I got your point and thanks for your enthusiasm. I will try with IPP or swscale.